# Sampling using PCA and maximizing variance

Tags: sampling, pca, experiment-design

In 6 forests, I've 3 variables that I know the values for all trees: $height$, $diameter$ and $density$. I can only cut some trees to know their $mass$. The question is how to choose the trees to cut?

As I supposed a linear model such as: $Mass = a_1 Diameter + a_2 Height + a_3 Density + a_4$ (or as mention in an answer $log(Mass) = a_1 log(Diameter) + a_2 log(Height) + a_3 log(Density) + a_4$), 
I thought to maximize the variance of the sampling to have the best fitting afterward. Is it correct to use a Principal Component Analysis over the 3 variables and then choose in the 2 first axes of the PCA the most spread out sampling ?

Is there another method to choose sampling by maximizing the variance over variables that I already know ?

Thank you.

Comment: This is an interesting question, and I will be curious to see the responses you get.  I just want to clarify that the theoretical relationship is multiplicative, **Mass = pi*Radius^2 * Height * Density**, so if you want to fit a linear model, you should do so with log transformed variables, **log(Mass) = a1*log(Diameter) + a2*log(Height) + a3*log(Density) + a4**.

Comment: The [Wikipedia article on optimal design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_design) lists no fewer than *eight* criteria. Because many of these are stated in terms of the information matrix or its inverse--both of which have direct relationships to the principal components--then PCA is implicitly involved in most of them.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I'm glad you think it's an interesting question, and really curious about the theory on "optimal design".